# Problem with wifi on kubuntu 15.04 with Realtek rtl8192cu USB dongle

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, kubuntu, realtek-wireless

I've recently installed 64bit version of kubuntu and science then I've been having issue with wifi. It work great for few minutes and then it disconnects but it shows that I am connected and I have to reconnect. What causes this problem, how to fix it?

Output of lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I do not see any pci wireless adapters. Is it a usb dongle?

Comment: Yup it's usb dongle.

Comment: Shall we guess it? Then give output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a better driver by running in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.